# How to use timestaffdiff in DerbySQL to find the records with the time gap not larger than 1 hour?

Tags: sql, select, timestamp, derby

So I've tried to use the timestamp diff to calculate and get the results with time gap not larger than 1 hour from the current time. However, it is not working as intended.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF( SQL_TSI_HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, STARTTIME)} <= 1
```

When I run the code, all results with gap more than 1 day are displayed, as screenshot below with my current timestamp as reference.
[the results returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3RVT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to swap the order of the two timestamp inputs to `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM schedule
WHERE {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_HOUR, STARTTIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)} <= 1;
```